# Sorting Datatable in Descending Order

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with columns   Brand,Section,Color,Len.,Section Type,desc., Wt, Qty, Rate,Total,Storage,Action

when I save data into the table i would like to get latest data at the top followed by older data i the datatable.Right now I am not getting the sorted data in the datatable even though I get them sorted properly from model and controller.

My script looks like following:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bar_list').dataTable( {

        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": App.settings.basePath + "inventory/requisition/barlist"
        +"/type/<?php echo $this->type; ?>/id/<?php echo $this->id; ?>"
        +"/barFilterSection/<?php echo $this->filterSection; ?>"
        +"/barFilterColor/<?php echo $this->filterColor; ?>"
        +"/barFilterLength/<?php echo $this->filterLength; ?>"

    });
```

How to display the data in descending order in the datatable without specifying columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bar_list').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ INDEX_NO_COLUMN, SORT_TYPE ]],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": App.settings.basePath + "inventory/requisition/barlist"
    +"/type/<?php echo $this->type; ?>/id/<?php echo $this->id; ?>"
    +"/barFilterSection/<?php echo $this->filterSection; ?>"
    +"/barFilterColor/<?php echo $this->filterColor; ?>"
    +"/barFilterLength/<?php echo $this->filterLength; ?>"

});
```

[Refer Link](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)